# Oracle silent install on Redhat Linux (The Global database name was left blank.)

Tags: linux, oracle, installation, redhat

I am installing Oracle 11g in silent mode using the response file that is in the database/response directory. It is three response files in that directory(i.e. dbca.rsp, db_install.rsp and netca.rsp). I am using db_install.rsp and customize its properties to use it in runInstaller command in database directory.

At first I want to know is it the right rsp file to install the Oracle server.

When I use this rsp file it seems it doesn't use the values I set in it fr example it asks me to give the My Oracle Support accounts while I set the DECLINE_SECURITY_UPDATES to TRUE. After I add that parameter in the command line as follow:

> ./runInstaller -silent responseFile=/home/oracle/db_install.rsp -showProgress DECLINE_SECURITY_UPDATES=TRUE

it asks me to specify the "Global database name" as follow:

> Starting Oracle Universal Installer...
>
> Checking Temp space: must be greater than 120 MB.   Actual 44950 MB
>   Passed Checking swap space: must be greater than 150 MB.   Actual 8015
>   MB    Passed Preparing to launch Oracle Universal Installer from
>   /tmp/OraInstall2014-02-14_06-40-50PM. Please wait
>   ...[oracle@somethin database]$ [FATAL] [INS-35071] Global database
>   name cannot be left blank.    CAUSE: The Global database name was left
>   blank.    ACTION: Specify a value for the Global database name.

I am sure I set that value in the rsp file. But it seems it doesn't recognize it. As I check the installation log in oraInventory/log directory it didn't recognize the SID value I already set.

Even before all the issues above it didn't recognize the ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_BASE that I have had set in the sb_install.rsp and I set it in environment variables in bash_profile.

I guess it is the wrong rsp file and the runInstaller cannot recognize the parameters in it.  I need to know how to force runInstaller to read the install configuration from the rsp file.

Answer (score 2):

> ./runInstaller -silent responseFile=/home/oracle/db_install.rsp
>   -showProgress DECLINE_SECURITY_UPDATES=TRUE

The above line is wronge. I changed it like the following and it works fine.

> ./runInstaller -silent -responseFile /home/oracle/db_install.rsp -showProgress